# Rewriting URL within tomcat html output

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure an external Apache front-end with a different URL to the backend tomcat app. I take tomcat's manager app as an example.

I would like users to access my page like externally like:
https://myhost.com/tomcat-manager

Internally, it gets redirected to 
http://localhost:8080/manager

I tried the following configuration in apache2 with mod_proxy and mod_rewrite:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on

  RewriteRule "/manager/(.*)$" https://myhost.com/tomcat-manager/$1 [P]
  ProxyPass /tomcat-manager http://localhost:8080/manager
  ProxyPassReverse /tomcat-manager http://localhost:8080/manager
```

It mostly works, but I dislike that the tomcat manager webapp outputs its links as "/manager" instead of "/tomcat-manager", forcing me to add the above mod_rewrite rule. Ideally, I would like the end-user to see only browser URLs of the pattern:

https://myhost.com/tomcat-manager/(whatever)

and never the following:

https://myhost.com/manager/(whatever)

Any suggestion to configure Apache without modifying the underlying webapp? Thanks!

Comment: rename the `webapps/manager` folder to `tomcat-manager` although in my setup `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` works fine without needing `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to preserve webapps/manager folder names? I mean, I would like to have the external URL format to be totally independent of the webapps folder architecture or naming conventions.

Comment: As I said, in my setup ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse works fine without needing RewriteRule.  You could try that.

Comment: I tried already. It only works if the internal webapp name happens to match the external URL name, e.g. http://my-host.com/manager. But if I change the external URL to something else, it ceases to work, because ProxyPass and ProxyReverse doesn't change the html output, only the redirects.

Comment: a good reason **not** to reference your context name in your code/html. Sorry I could not help more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. It is Apache's mod_proxy_html. I enabled the corresponding modules and fixed Ubuntu's mod_proxy_html missing configuration as stated here: https://serverfault.com/questions/684905/proxyhtmlurlmap-not-working-in-apache2-4

Then, I added the following configuration code:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://localhost:8080/manager/ /tomcat-manager/
ProxyHTMLURLMap /manager/ /tomcat-manager/
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
RequestHeader      unset  Accept-Encoding
```

And that's it. Now, I can access http://myhost.com/tomcat-manager and the html code within is also rewritten!